# xmltodict xml parsing Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have managed to obtain the data I need from an online XML doc using xmltodict (it is very user friendly and I liked how intuitive it is). However, because the data was parsed as a dictionary, I'm having trouble manipulating it in the way that I need. I need to change the time to a `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format and move the three columns to a tab-delimited text file. Here is my code, which is not functioning, but gives an idea of what I want to do:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
url='http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.6062&lon=-122.3321&FcstType=digitalDWML'
r = requests.get(url)

import xmltodict
result = xmltodict.parse(r.text)
data = []
d = result['dwml']['data']['time-layout']['start-valid-time']
d = dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
#print d
pop = result['dwml']['data']['parameters']['probability-of-precipitation']['value']
#print("probability-of-precipitation =", pop)
hqpf = result['dwml']['data']['parameters']['hourly-qpf']['value']
#print("hourly-qpf =", hqpf)

data = data.append([d,
                   pop,
                   hqpf])
with open ('KBFI_2.txt','w') as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join(map(str,i)) + '\n' for i in data)
```

Is there a way that I can change the format of the dictionaries so I can manipulate this?? Very new to Python and XML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate dictionaries freely without changing its format. It's just a couple errors in your code preventing you from doing it correctly.
To change value of dictionary you have assign new value directly to key:

```
d = result['dwml']['data']['time-layout']['start-valid-time']
result['dwml']['data']['time-layout']['start-valid-time'] = dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Second error is that list.append returns None and you assigning it back to your list variable. Just do

```
data.append([d, pop, hqpf])  # without data=
```

and you'll be fine